# INotifyPropertyChanged not working as expected

Tags: wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a little trouble with INotifyPropertyChanged. I implemented it lots of times, however this case is different. I would like to create the following application:
[image: mockup]

There are multiple tab containers, which are bound to different ObservableCollections of Entities. Now I would like to show the name of the currently (last) selected Entity. To achieve this, I've created created a DependencyProperty CurrentEntity in the Window class and assign via SelectionChanged on the TabControls the current Entity.

```
private void SelectionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentEntity = e.NewItems[0] as Entity;
}
```

The TextBlock which, in the above picture, displays VideoA looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding CurrentEntity.Name}" />
```

Now whenever I select a new Tab, the Text in the TextBlock changes accordingly. However when I change the the name of an Entity (inside a TextBox in a Tab, which is also bound to the Entity), the text in the TextBlock doesn't change. I have to select another Tab and then change back to the Tab where I changed the Name to see the newly entered name in the TextBlock. Basically, this is my problem, I would like to see the text changing without selecting another Tab first (and yes, I de-focused from the TextBox inside the Tab after entering the new Name).

Has anyone an idea where the problem is?

My "architecture" looks (more or less ;-)) like this:
[image: uml]

Comment: What little code you've given doesn't even make sense. You set CurrentEntity but then bind to CurrentElement. Which is it? Please just post your code instead of (or - even better - in addition to) the diagrams. Elsewise, it's just a guessing game for us.

Comment: It's CurrentEntity, not CurrentElement, thanks for pointing this out. I don't think that posting a few hundert lines of code makes anything easier, especially since suspect it has something to do with the overall design and not with the code. However, I'll try to paste something together that makes sense without copying the entire code from 3 files ;-)

Comment: What's the `TextBox` binding look like? And my best guess is the `CurrentEntity` is being bound to a different copy of the item than the `TabControl` has. You can do a quick check by finding out if `CurrentEntity == SomeItemCollection[SelectedIndex]`

Answer (score -1):

ObservableCollection just means that the event to update UI is kicked off when the collection changes, you add, remove, re-order, etc.

Altering an the property of an item in an ObservableCollection, such as a string, doesn't not actually cause a UI event.

Does the object you have inside the ObservableCollection implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: As you can see above, I mentioned, that Entity implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: My pardon's Danu, I definitely missed that.